# Ruby GET NET HTTP request does not work with AUTHORIZATION and ACCEPT when passed in a header

Tags: ruby

I've been using the code below to call a third party API .  This code works fine (i've changed the url and the credentials but the structure of the code is the same) :

```
require 'base64'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

######################################################################
# Get the token first
######################################################################
consumer_key    = "my_key"
consumer_secret = "my_secret"

credentials = Base64.encode64("#{consumer_key}:#{consumer_secret}").gsub("\n", '')
url = "https://mysite/token"
body = "grant_type=client_credentials"

headers = {
  "Authorization" => "Basic #{credentials}",
  "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
}

r = HTTParty.post(url, body: body, headers: headers)
bearer_token = JSON.parse(r.body)['access_token']

######################################################################
# Use the token in a call as authorisation header
######################################################################
api_url = "https://apisite/the_value_i_am_looking_for_in_the_api"

url = URI.parse(api_url)
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
req.use_ssl = true

# If we are just passing a key that doesn't need to be in the token format
headers = {
  'Authorization' => "Bearer #{bearer_token}"
}

# Get the response back (he data is in the response body: resp.body )
resp = req.get(url, headers)
```

My issue is that the API providers have changed their API so you now need to pass an "accept" into the call via the header.  I used POSTMAN to make the call, added the accept to the header and was able to get it working without issue.  So far so good.

I then changed my ruby code to extend the headers section to include the accept, using the code below:

```
headers = {
  'Authorization' => "Bearer #{bearer_token}",
  'Accept' => 'application/vnd.bluebadge-api.v1+json'
}
```

I've not added an accept to a header before so I may have gotten the syntax wrong.

However, this returns an unauthorised 401 response code:

```
#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>
```

I thought I might have the credentials wrong so remove the accept, try again and this changes to a 406 response code:

```
#<Net::HTTPNotAcceptable 406 Not Acceptable readbody=true>
```

If I examine the response I get the message I would expect that the accept header is not the supported version.  So I know the credentials are correct (and the fact they match the postman credentials which works):

```
"{\"apiVersion\": \"1\",\"context\": null,\"id\": null,\"method\": null,\"error\": {\"code\": null,\"message\": null,\"reason\": \"Accept header version is not a currently supported version.\",\"errors\": null}}\n"
```

So I know all my credentials are correct because I've copied them into the postman request which works with no errors.  The value for the accept header is correct because I copied that from a working postman request too.

I am at a loss for why this wouldn't work.

I've looked through the NET HTTP library and cant find anything to help me there.  I've seen a couple of posts elsewhere which I've tried and they haven't worked either.

I appreciate any help in trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  I was using the credentials from the production environment to get the token then trying to query the test environment API.  In my defence they look very similar (only 3 characters different).  I think I had a case of the code blindness.

The code I posted does work when I put the correct URL for the environments.

I also found that I could use this:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://myapi/some_text")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{bearer_token}"
request["Accept"] = "application/vnd.bluebadge-api.v1+json"
response = http.request(request)
```

Or using HTTParty like this:

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://myapi/some_text', {
  headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{bearer_token}", "Accept" => "application/vnd.bluebadge-api.v1+json" }
})
```

I would prefer the format of my orginal code or the HTTparty code because it is easy to see from the code that you're passing headers.  Hopefully this will help others to double check their authorization credentials...